# how to use where clause by sequence of ids

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-operator

I have a sequence of `ids` that merged by a comma :

```
$ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' ;
select * from ads WHERE id = $ids ...
```

now how can I get content of `ads` table by these `ids` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using PHP. You can build the SQL like this:

```
$ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id IN ('.$ids.')';
//execute the query (don't use mysql_* function ;) )
```

Since MySQL 5.6 you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` too:

```
$ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '".$ids."')";
//execute the query (don't use mysql_* function ;) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**IN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads 
WHERE id IN ($ids);
```